# When attaching less than all files I get a "could not access file" error

Tags: php, phpmailer

This all worked under an older version of PHP, and I know exactly where and what the problem is. Just not sure how to fix it.

I have a form that has other forms of input but this is the part I need help with.

```
Attachment(s):<br> <input type="file" name="uploadfile[]"/><br>
               <input type="file" name="uploadfile[]"><br>
               <input type="file" name="uploadfile[]"><br>
```

And the code that deals with the file inputs:

```
$total = count($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i = $total; $i++) {
    $name = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$i];
   $path = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
   $mail->AddAttachment($path,$name);
}
```

Now the problem is, unless all three inputs from the form have a file in them, it throws an error if there is only one file it gives:

"could not access file. Could not access file". (2 errors)

If there are two files it gives:

"Could not access file" (1 error)

and if there are three files there is no error.

So I know it is in the count() function that is the issue

Comment: if you use a foreach() loop you dont have to count

Comment: When I use foreach, for some reason none of the files attach.

Comment: `print_r($_FILES);` lets see what your actually dealing with

Comment: Do what Dagon says, but also read the docs on handling file uploads because your code is not safe.

Comment: @Dagon This is what prints: 
'Could not access file: Array
 Array ( [uploadfile] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => BMS_Logo_profile.png [1] => [2] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/png [1] => [2] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpevvVWm [1] => [2] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 4 [2] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 189263 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 ) ) )'